# Calling timeIntervalSince1970 in different devices

Tags: ios, timestamp, synchronization

From the following links, does it mean that if calling `timeIntervalSince1970` in different devices at SAME TIME(theoretically), the timestamp will be the same?

- [triggering an event simultaneously on multiple iOS devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16489899/triggering-an-event-simultaneously-on-multiple-ios-devices)
- [Different result for [NSDate date] in several devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20425868/diffrent-result-for-nsdate-date-in-several-devices)
- http://support.apple.com/kb/ta38641

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, they theoretically could be the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`timeIntervalSince1970` is the number of seconds since 1 January 1970, GMT and therefore
independent of the devices time zone, the chosen date format etc. So theoretically, if the clocks
of two devices were completely in sync, the value of

```
[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970]
```

would be the same at the same absolute point in time.

In practice, there will always be a difference. The device clock is never 100%
correct, and a user can even disable the automatic time synchronisation and set an
arbitrary time manually.

Comment: Thank you for confirming my idea, Martin!

Comment: I don't understand. You say: "therefore independent of the devices time zone." Then you give the condition "if the clocks of two devices were completely in sync" 

If it is independent of the time zone,  why/when would we need such a sync? What am I missing here? 
Thanks.

Comment: @MuratYasar: Because clocks are not 100% precise. Even if they are synchronized with a network time server at regular intervals, chances are that two computer clocks differ *slightly.*

Comment: @MartinR thanks for answering. So if one device's time is set manually to a time different than the other device's time which is set automatically, will NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970 print the same number? 

Secondly, if a device in Canada and Turkey(both devices times are set automatically) are both printing the NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970, will they print the same number or what?

Comment: If you start up a swift repl and punch in `Date().timeIntervalSince1970`, then go to System Preferences > Date & Time and change the **time zone** manually, and finally re-run `Date().timeIntervalSince1970` you will see only a few seconds of difference (the time it took to click through the UI). By contrast, if you change the **time** manually (by unselecting "Set time and date automatically"), and re-run `Date().timeIntervalSince1970` you will see a large difference in seconds (the seconds you manually adjusted the time by)

Comment: @MuratYasar so to answer your questions:
"So if one device's time is set manually to a time different than the other device's time which is set automatically, will NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970 print the same number?"
*No*
"Secondly, if a device in Canada and Turkey(both devices times are set automatically) are both printing the NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970, will they print the same number or what?"
*They will be very close, but not identical due to the synchronization differences that Martin mentioned (e.g. the clocks are synchronized off a network at different times)*